# Считывание чисел до конца строки с помощью cin.peek()

Tags: c++, поток-ввода

Мне нужно считать числа до конца строки, я реализовал это с помощью cin.peek():

```cpp
int a;
while(cin.peek() != '\n')
{
    cin >> a;
    // some pieces of code
}
```

Но возникла проблема: в то время как строчки по типу `1 2 3` этот код обрабатывает правильно, для такой же строчки, но с пробелом в конце, работа программы продолжается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему возникает такая проблема, и как её решать?

Comment: Во входных данных могут быть не натуральные числа?

Comment: @Yernar могут быть только целые

Comment: Почему же мой ответ не подходит?

Comment: @Yernar он подходит, но не решает мою проблему

Answer (score 2):

Получается так, потому что у вас остался пробел(ы) перед `'\n'` и соответственно `cin.peek()` смотрит на этот пробел и условие будет `true`, те будет ждать очередного числа.

Если нужно считать неопределённое количество чисел в строке, то можно считать эту строку и передать в `std::istringstream` и уже дальше читать из `stringstream`, пробелы в конце не помешают.

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);

istringstream inp(s);

int a;
while (inp >> a) {
    // some pieces of code
}
```

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 0):

`istream::peek` не забирает символ из потока. Если текущий символ не перевод строки, прогресса нет, программа зацикливается.

Можно обойтись без чтения в промежуточную строку, хотя вариант со строкой самый простой. Тем не менее, читаем из потока символы ([istream::get](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)), если попался перевод строки, останавливаемся, если не пробельный символ, возвращаем его обратно в поток ([istream::unget](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/unget/)) и останавливаемся:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

bool skip_spaces_till_eol(std::istream &is) {
    char c;
    while (is.get(c)) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            return true;
        }
        if (!std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))) {
            is.unget();
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    while (std::cin >> n) {
        std::cout << "number: " << n << '\n';
        if (skip_spaces_till_eol(std::cin)) {
            std::cout << "done\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```